# Checking .isdigit() on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the error saying `AttributeError, 'int' object has no Attribute 'isdigit'`. Could you explain to me what that means, and what I should do or change?

```
def digi():

    number = input("Choose a number: ")

    if number.isdigit() == True:
        number = int(number)
        if number > 100:
            print("number is greater than 100 =",number > 100)

        elif number < 100:
            print("number is greater than 100 =",number > 100)


    else:
        print("input must be 'int'")


digi()
```

Comment: You're not actually on Python 3. Get Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. I just did that and it worked.

Comment: Use `isdecimal` not `isdigit` (and Python 3). `isdigit` is an unsafe test because it recognises characters like unicode power-of-2, ² , as a digit which can not be converted to integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ints do not have `isdigit()` defined. `isdigit()` is a method inside of strings that checks if the string is a valid integer.

In python3 the `input()` function always returns a string, but if you are getting that error that means that number was somehow an int. You are using python 2.

To fix your predicament replace `input()` with `raw_input()`.

Or just get python3

Comment: @vaultah noted :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for, `isdigit()` is NOT required.

```
def digi():
    number = input("Choose a number: ")

    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number > 100:
            print("number is greater than 100")

        else:
            print("number is less than or equal to 100")

    except ValueError:
        print("input must be 'int'")

digi()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I would suggest the following modification.
def digi():

```
number = str(input("Choose a number: "))

if number.isdigit() == True:
    number = int(number)
    if number > 100:
        print("number is greater than 100 =",number > 100)

    elif number < 100:
        print("number is greater than 100 =",number > 100)


else:
    print("input must be 'int'")
```

Input will evaluate whatever you entered and the result of evaluation will be returned.

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)